# Get iteration, team, project from a work item in azure devops api

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api

I have successfully retrieved work items from the api. I can also retrieve iterations/teams/projects etcetera from the api. My issue is that I have work item objects that I want to reference to iterations/teams/projects. I have **not** found a way to retrieve this info from the existing info on the work item. It *appears* that an iteration path doesn't always relate to a real iteration??? Are there fields in a work item that I can use to reference projects/teams/iterations.

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/work/iterations?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/core/teams?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/core/projects?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wit/work%20items?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the missing element was getting iterations from this api:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wit/classification%20nodes/get?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1
and traversing the iteration path up and down and giving it a `$depth` to get children